# How to extend the transformer in Kafka Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am working on a Kafka streaming implementation of a word counter in Scala in which I extended the transformer:

```
class WordCounter extends Transformer[String, String, (String, Long)]
```

It is then called in the stream as follows:

```
val counter: KStream[String, Long] = filtered_record.transform(new WordCounter, "count")
```

However, I am getting the error below when running my program via sbt:

```
[error]  required: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.TransformerSupplier[String,String,org.apache.kafka.streams.KeyValue[String,Long]]
```

I can't seem to figure out how to fix it, and could not find any appropriate Kafka example of a similar implementation. 
Anyone got any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try `filtered_record.transform(() => new WordCounter, "count")`.

Answer (score 3):

The signature of `transform()` is:

```
  def transform[K1, V1](transformerSupplier: TransformerSupplier[K, V, KeyValue[K1, V1]],
                        stateStoreNames: String*): KStream[K1, V1]
```

Thus, `transform()` takes a `TransformerSupplier` as first argument not a `Transformer`.

See also the [javadocs](https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#transform-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.TransformerSupplier-java.lang.String...-)